# AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal get NullPointerException in storm bolt

Tags: nullpointerexception, apache-storm, stringbuffer

online system, the storm Bolt get NullPointerException,though I think I check it before line 61; It gets NullPointerException once in a while;

```
import ***.KeyUtils;
import ***.redis.PipelineHelper;
import ***.redis.PipelinedCacheClusterClient;
import **.redis.R2mClusterClient;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * RedisBolt batch operate
 */
public class RedisBolt implements IRichBolt {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 737015318988609460L;
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private static long logEmitNumber = 0;
    private static StringBuffer totalCmds = new StringBuffer();
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private OutputCollector _collector;
    private R2mClusterClient r2mClusterClient;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector outputCollector) {
        _collector = outputCollector;
        if (applicationContext == null) {
            applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/spring-config-redisbolt.xml");
        }
        if (r2mClusterClient == null) {
            r2mClusterClient = (R2mClusterClient) applicationContext.getBean("r2mClusterClient");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        String log = tuple.getString(0);
        String lastCommands = tuple.getString(1);

        try {
            //log count
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(log)) {
                logEmitNumber++;
            }

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lastCommands)) {
                if(totalCmds==null){
                    totalCmds = new StringBuffer();
                }
                totalCmds.append(lastCommands);//line 61
            }

            //日志数量控制
            int numberLimit = 1;
            String flow_log_limit = r2mClusterClient.get(KeyUtils.KEY_PIPELINE_LIMIT);
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(flow_log_limit)) {
                try {
                    numberLimit = Integer.parseInt(flow_log_limit);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    numberLimit = 1;
                    logger.error("error", e);
                }
            }

            if (logEmitNumber >= numberLimit) {
                StringBuffer _totalCmds = new StringBuffer(totalCmds);
                try {
                    //pipeline submit
                    PipelinedCacheClusterClient pip = r2mClusterClient.pipelined();
                    String[] commandArray = _totalCmds.toString().split(KeyUtils.REDIS_CMD_SPILT);
                    PipelineHelper.cmd(pip, commandArray);
                    pip.sync();
                    pip.close();
                    totalCmds = new StringBuffer();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("error", e);
                }

                logEmitNumber = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(new StringBuffer("====RedisBolt error for log=[ ").append(log).append("] \n commands=[").append(lastCommands).append("]").toString(), e);
            _collector.reportError(e);
            _collector.fail(tuple);
        }

        _collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {

    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

exception info:

java.lang.NullPointerException at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:113) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415) at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237) at com.jd.jr.dataeye.storm.bolt.RedisBolt.execute(RedisBolt.java:61) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$tuple_action_fn__5046.invoke(executor.clj:727) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4965.invoke(executor.clj:459) at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4480.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40) at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:472) at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:451) at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:73) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$fn__5057$fn__5110.invoke(executor.clj:846) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

can anyone give me some advice to find the reason.

Comment: and the java version "1.7.0_71"

Answer (score 0):

That is really odd thing to happen. Please read the code for two classes.

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuffer.java

AbstractStringBuilder has constructor with no args which doesn't allocate the field 'value', which makes accessing the 'value' field being NPE. Any constructors in StringBuffer use that constructor. So maybe some odd thing happens in serialization/deserialization and unfortunately 'value' field in  AbstractStringBuilder is being null.

Maybe initializing totalCmds in prepare() would be better, and also you need to consider synchronization (thread-safety) between bolts. prepare() can be called per bolt instance so fields are thread-safe, but class fields are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the problem maybe;

the key point is

"StringBuffer _totalCmds = new StringBuffer(totalCmds);" and " totalCmds.append(lastCommands);//line 61"

when new a object, It takes serval steps:

(1) allocate memory and return reference

(2) initialize

if append after (1) and before (2) then the StringBuffer.java extends AbstractStringBuilder.java

```
 /**
 * The value is used for character storage.
 */
char[] value;
```

value is not initialized;so this will get null:

```
@Override
public synchronized void ensureCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    if (minimumCapacity > value.length) {
        expandCapacity(minimumCapacity);
    }
}
```

this blot has a another question, some data maybe lost under a multithreaded environment